# How to add value to a value of certain clolumn and row in datatable C#

Tags: c#, foreach, datatable

I have two datatables:

1.`dtEmployee`:

```
|agent_id|agent_name|sum|
```

2.`dtReport`:

```
|sale_date|agent_id|sum |
------------------------
```

For each record in `dtReport` I need to find `agent_id` in `dtEmployee` and add the value of dtReport["sum"] to dtEmployee["sum"]:

```
foreach (DataRow r in dtReport)
{
    DataRow empRow = dtEmployee.find(dtReport["agent_id"]);
    empRow["sum"] += r["sum"];
}
```

Is there a way that would allow me to accomplish this?

Comment: you want to do it only for runtime?. or you want  to save this value in table also?

Comment: Yes, do the addition and save it to table.

Comment: ok,so why are you doing this in c#?. you can do this in sql also. Is there any condition to fetch the records first in datatable and then save back to table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this works:

```
private void AddValue(string agent_id, decimal sum)
{
    DataRow[] row= dtEmployee.Select("agent_id= '"+agent_id+"'"); 
    //since only one record with this agent_id, we take first record of array -> row[0]
    decimal dSum= Convert.ToDecimal(row[0][column]);
    dSum+= sum;
    row[0]["sum"] = dSum;
}
```

and insert this function into loop:

```
foreach (DataRow r in dtReport)
{
    AddValue(r["agent_id"], r["sum"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in many ways.

**Option 1 :**

```
foreach(DataRow row in dtEmployee.Rows)
{
    var update = dtReport.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Field<string>("agent_id") == row.Field<string>("agent_id"));

    if(update !=null)
    row.SetField<float>("sum",  update.Field<float>("sum"));      
}
```

**Option 2**

Another option would be creating new table by joining `DataTables`

```
var results = from t1 in dtEmployee.AsEnumerable()
              join t2 in dtReport.AsEnumerable() 
                on t1.Field<int>("agent_id") equals t2.Field<int>("agent_id")
              select new { t1, t2 };

// Now we can construct new DataTable

DataTable result = new DataTable() ;
result.Columns.Add("agent_id", typeof(System.Int32));
result.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(System.String));
result.Columns.Add("sum", typeof(float));

foreach(var dr in results )
{
    DataRow newRow = results.NewRow();
    newRow["agent_id"] = dr.t1.Field<int>("agent_id");
    newRow["agent_name"] = dr.t1.Field<string>("agent_name");
    newRow["sum"] = dr.t2.Field<float>("sum");

    // When all columns have been filled in then add the row to the table
    results.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

Working [sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Na3WO6)

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. Given that your agent_id and sum are integer.

```
foreach (DataRow r in dtReport.Rows)
{
    dtEmployee.Select(string.Format("agent_id = {0}", r["agent_id"])).ToList<DataRow>().ForEach(
             v => { v["sum"] = (v.IsNull("sum") ? 0 : v.Field<int>("sum")) + (r.IsNull("sum") ? 0 : r.Field<int>("sum")); });
}
```

Or equivalent code

```
foreach (DataRow r in dtReport.Rows)
{
    DataRow[] empRow = dtEmployee.Select("agent_id = " + r["agent_id"]);
    for (int i = 0; i < empRow.Length; i++)
    {
        empRow[i]["sum"] = (empRow[i].IsNull("sum") ? 0 : (int)empRow[i]["sum"]) + (r.IsNull("sum") ? 0 : (int)r["sum"]);
    }
}
```